# How to edit stored procedures in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created `stored procedure in phpMyAdmin` but now I have to `alter` it.
Is there any way to edit it from `phpMyAdmin`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to edit routines in phpmyadmin -

[image]

Please check the image.

When open a database and scroll down there is a Routine button and it shows all the routines.

Just click on the edit button and you will be able to edit it from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to drop it and then recreate it.

but maybe the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` will work

Comment: thanks for answering. But thing is the procedure is huge and I dont want to lose it. So Im searching quicker way to only edit the procedure :)

Comment: have you tried `create or replace` in the creation script of you procedure ? Do you have a script for the procedure ?

Comment: Ok do you see you procedure in the routines tab in phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: yep I can see. also I did `Options -> Full texts -> Go` and I can see my whole script. But `DB` is really huge and other procedures are there. so i dont want to mess with it.

Comment: So if you can se the stored procedure you've got a little pen to edit it. If not you probably should ask the correct right to do it !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102482/discussion-between-airliquide-and-rishi-vishwakarma).